# Show/Hide divs with switch case from dropdownlistFor in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

New to MVC and trying to rewrite an older application from C#. 
Out of the 50 states in the dropdownlist only 2 have separate divs, all others are "default". 
       $(document).ready(); {
        $("#State").change(function () {

```
        var dropdownval = $("#State").val();
        switch (dropdownval) {
            case 'NH':
                $("#NH").show();
                break;
            case 'WA':
                $("#WA").show();
                break;
            default:
                $("#Default").show();
                break;
        }
    }
    )
};
```

DropDownListFor

```
<div class="form-group; flex-container">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="control-label col-md-2">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StateList"], "Select State")
</div>
```

Divs to show/hide based on state selected:

```
        <div id="WA" class="StateSelect" hidden="hidden" style='font-size: 10pt;'>
    <label class="control-label">Washington</label>

<div id="NH" class="StateSelect" hidden="hidden" style='font-size: 10pt;'>
    <label class="control-label">New Hampshire</label>

<div id="Default" class="StateSelect" hidden="hidden" style='font-size: 10pt;'>
    <label class="control-label">Default</label>
```

Comment: What is happening and what do you expect to happen? It is not clear from your post.

Comment: I don't think you can simply use `NH.show`. use proper JQuery selector to show and hide.

Comment: `$("#NH").show()` something like this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please take time to read the [tour] and specifically [ask].  Your question does not have a clear problem statement - can you clarify exactly which part you are having an issue with.

Comment: As it's not clear from the question where the issue is, this is left as a comment: Look at the rendered HTML, you'll see your `select` has an ID that matches the viewmodel's property.  You can use this to wire up the event.  `$("#State").change(function () {`.

Comment: Sorry. As this is my first post, I am not sure where my edit ended up. I am trying to show/hide the divs based on the state selected in the dropdownlistfor. The div properties are also set to hidden so I am really not sure how to connect the dropdown selection to the js switch to run through the cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind jquery inside the ready, you are doing it outside.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".StateSelect").change(function () {

    var dropdownval = $("#StateSelect").val();
    switch (dropdownval) {
        case 'NH':
           $("#NH").show();
           $("#WA").hide();
           $("#Default").hide();
            break;
        case 'WA':
          $("#WA").show();
           $("#Default").hide();
           $("#NH").hide();
            break;
        default:
           $("#Default").show();
           $("#WA").hide();
           $("#NH").hide();
            break;
        }
    }
    );
});
```

Notice I added a function inside the ready(...)

You can find more on how to initialise document ready here

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: This is working as far as showing the div when selected but it is not hiding if I change the selection for example, if I selected NH it displays but if I select WA, NH is still displayed and WA div is displayed below it and so on.

Comment: See my edited answer. You need to hide the others. Obviously the code can be cleaner and be reusable. My intention is just a guide.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your code to something like this

```
     $(document).ready(); {
    $(".StateSelect").change(function () {

        var dropdownval = $("#StateSelect").val();
        switch (dropdownval) {
            case 'NH':
               $("#NH").show()
                break;
            case 'WA':
              $("#WA").show()
                break;
            default:
               $("#Default").show()

                break;
        }
    }
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `on('change', function(){`. Secondly, you can compress this code like below, by hiding all the elements, and showing the required ones based on the selections:

```
$(".StateSelect").on('change', function() {
  $("#Default, #NH, #WA").hide();
  var dropdownval = $("#StateSelect").val();
  switch (dropdownval) {
    case 'NH':
    case 'WA':
      $("#" + dropdownval).show();
      break;
    default:
      $("#Default").show();
      break;
  }
});
```